# Adding stuff into a hidden file

Tags: bash, unix, hidden-files

I'm trying to add a `filename:filesfullpath` into a hidden file, so every time the user runs the script and calls in a file, the file and full file path would be added into the hidden file, presented in the following way:

```
filename:filepath
filename:filepath

..
```

I know how to get the file name and the filepath, but I don't know how to put it all in one line with the colon and into the hidden file.

I have

```
flink=$(readlink -e $1)
fname=$(basename $flink)

fname":"flink >> .hiddenfile
```

but obviously that didn't work.

Comment: simply `echo` it? Right now your "string" is being executed as a command and fails obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote your variables. For example:

```
flink=$(readlink -e "$1")
fname=$(basename "$flink")

echo "${fname}:${flink}" >> /path/to/.hiddenfile
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why we need to use the quotes and what does ${variable} mean still having trouble knowing when to using that.

Comment: @Nabz Failing to use quotes or brackets can cause all sorts of problems with word splitting and variable expansion. You should almost always include them for defensive programming, although experienced programmers may omit them in special use cases where word splitting or quoting are undesirable. For starters, see: [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), [Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html), and [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).